# Is there a way to negate a boolean returned to variable?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django site, with an `Item` object that has a boolean property `active`. I would like to do something like this to toggle the property from False to True and vice-versa:

```
def toggle_active(item_id):
    item = Item.objects.get(id=item_id)
    item.active = !item.active
    item.save()
```

This syntax is valid in many C-based languages, but seems invalid in Python. Is there another way to do this WITHOUT using:

```
if item.active:
    item.active = False
else:
    item.active = True
item.save()
```

The native python `neg()` method seems to return the negation of an integer, not the negation of a boolean.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You can do this:

```
item.active = not item.active
```

That should do the trick :)

Answer (score 17):

I think you want

```
item.active = not item.active
```

Answer (score 14):

`item.active = not item.active` is the pythonic way

Answer (score 10):

Another (less <strike>concise</strike> readable, more arithmetic) way to do it would be:

```
item.active = bool(1 - item.active)
```

Comment: +1 OMG, never knew this was possible, it does make sense but I never thought about it!! Great answer! (Though `bool(1-True)` is a bit slower then `not True`)

Comment: Possible, yes.  Useful?  Not likely!  There are tons of such ugly things you can do with most any language, but this is just terribly confusing for most readers.  Maybe in a very special context this could make sense...

Answer (score 7):

The negation for booleans is `not`.

```
def toggle_active(item_id):
    item = Item.objects.get(id=item_id)
    item.active = not item.active
    item.save()
```

Thanks guys, that was a lightning fast response!

Answer (score 5):

Its simple to do :

```
item.active = not item.active
```

So, finally you will end up with :

```
def toggleActive(item_id):
    item = Item.objects.get(id=item_id)
    item.active = not item.active
    item.save()
```